# How can I pause a docusign envelope created from template?

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an envelope from a template (which I have created using Docusign website UI) with a second signer which the envelope will be emailed to after the first signer is finished, but I want to be able to pause and unpause this through the API.  The process works as designed without the added workflow_step, but returns an error with the workflow_step added.

```
envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new({
    status: 'sent',
    templateId: template_id
})

signer1 = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new({
    email: signer1_email,
    name: signer1_name,
    roleName: 'signer1',
    clientUserId: signer_client_id,
    recipientId: 1,
    routingOrder: 1
})                                              
signer2 = DocuSign_eSign::TemplateRole.new({
    email: signer2_email,
    name: signer2_name,
    roleName: 'signer2',
    recipientId: 2,
    routingOrder: 2
})

envelope_definition.template_roles = [signer1, signer2]   

workflow_step = DocuSign_eSign::WorkflowStep.new(
  action: 'pause_before',
  triggerOnItem: 'routing_order',
  itemId: 2
)
workflow = DocuSign_eSign::Workflow.new(workflowSteps: [workflow_step])
envelope_definition.workflow = workflow
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

If you can't add workflow steps to an envelope created from a template, can I add it to the template somehow?

Comment: What is the error? Even better, please update (edit) your question to include your API log (request and response). Use the [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) feature. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check/accept the best answer to your question. Thank you 

Comment: Thanks for the tip on activating the logs!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a bug. Please ask your DocuSign support contact to add your company's information to internal bug report ARR-586.

### Workaround

This workaround was reported to work:

1. Create an envelope that uses the template and set the template roles. **But** set the **status** to `created`. This will create a draft envelope.
2. Use the [EnvelopeWorkflows:update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeworkflowdefinition/updateenvelopeworkflowdefinition/) API method to add the workflow.

   ```
   {
      "workflowSteps": [
          {
            "action": "pause_before",
            "triggerOnItem": "routing_order",
            "itemId": 2
          }
      ]
   }
   ```
3. Use the [Envelopes:update](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/update/) method to change the status to `sent`

Please add a comment to this answer if this technique worked for you.

Comment: @shafe -- I updated the answer

Comment: Do you have any insight into the error I'm getting while updating the status to `sent`?

Comment: @shafe -- please ask a new question if you're having trouble with updating an envelope to `sent`

Comment: Hi Larry, I resolved the sent issue, but the solution does not seem to work.  It still sends to the second signer via email immediately after the first signature.  Is there another possible workaround I can try?

Comment: Please contact DocuSign developer support to debug why the pause is not working. Include your API log. Does the account include the workflow pause actions feature? You don't need a support contract to contact developer support.